# C# Question: File Names

Tags: c#

I have a file called o.FileName it has a unwanted ".crash" at the end of it, how can I remove it?  I tryed "o.FileName = o.FileName - ".crash";" it didn't work because it was a string

Edit: What I want to do is open a file with a OpenFileDialog then if it has a .crash or a .crash.crash at the end of it remove it and save it

Answer (score 3):

Was the 'o.' the object reference?:

```
o.Filename = o.Filename.Replace(".crash", "");
```

otherwise:

```
filename = filename.Replace(".crash", "");
```

To actually rename the physical file:

```
File.Move(originalFilename, renamedFilename);
```

Comment: What I want to do is open a file with a OFD then if it has a .crash or a .crash.crash at the end of it remove it and save it
What I have: 

OpenFileDialog o = new OpenFileDialog();
if (o.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
return;
else
{
o.FileName = o.FileName - ".crash" ;
}

Answer (score 2):

Check that the string actually ends with ".crash" using the [System.String.EndsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) method. Drop the trailing ".crash" using [System.String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

```
if(o.FileName.EndsWith(".crash"))
    o.Filename = o.Filename.Replace(".crash", "");
```